# How to manage the InAppPurchase subscriptions

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am doing one application.In that i implemented In App Purchase with Auto renewal subscription.First i subscribed for one month and got the receipt from apple.And when i try to send the receipt to server,due to some problem i am unable to send a receipt to my server.And i didn't store the receipt in my local DB also.Whenever next time i will try to open my application,my server giving the alert like "Please subscribe".So if i try to subscribe once again,apple will again deduct the money or not.Can i get the receipt from the apple.

Answer (score 0):

Every user can only have one subscription at one time. Apple give him an alert that he already has this subscription.

You have to implement subscription restoring option for users. Here is a nice guide in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

Comment: If we again send the request to apple for subscription.what happen.